# Channel Images - Call to undefined method stdClass

Tags: devdemon, channel-images, php-errors, server-migration

We did a migration of an EE website from a server to DigitalOcean.

After we managed to change every route and everything, it seems that we can't upload images into channel images anymore.

it gives the following error:

Severity: Warning

Message:  Creating default object from empty value

Filename: channel_images/ajax.channel_images.php

Line Number: 369

Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::run() in /var/www/html/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/ajax.channel_images.php on line 371

EE 2.9.0
Latest Channel Images
The difference between the servers is that the current one has Latest PHP library.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. It was caused by having Imagick upload actions set for some Channel Images fields but not having ImageMagick itself installed on the new server. Once I installed ImageMagick, images uploaded without a problem.